# Macro factory and argument passed at calling

Tags: macros

I am making a factory macro (A) that produces another macro (B). Macro B consists in affecting what it gets as parameters to variables when called.
I am currently able to do all this without A, but this is not scalable, because it requires a lot of rewritting.

I guess that what I am missing here is the reference to an argument that must be expanded during the calling of B. I tried to use multiple `#` because this seems to be nested arguments, but I feel like this is not what I need.

The point I am struggling with is :
"`#1` (to point to the first argument within the function calling self function (ie `\variable1`))"  should be replaced by "Laetitia", because it's the first argument of the macro B.

You will find in the MWE :

- automation trial 1 : I tried without `xparse`
- automation trial 2 : with `xparse`
- the handmade code of what I want to achieve.

All 3 can be executed, one at the time, by switching the `\iffalse`/`\iftrue` instruction in the beginning.

Any pointer would be helpful!

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
% package pour utiliser une macro nested ac ses propres args
\usepackage{xparse}
\errorcontextlines32
\begin{document}
%==================================================================================
%     Prerequisite : lines of code to define variableI to variableXVI
%==================================================================================
\newcommand{\DefinitVariable}[1]{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname variable\Roman{#1}\endcsname{}%
    }%
%    Loop for defining all the variable
\newcounter{ctr}
\loop
    \stepcounter{ctr}
    \expandafter\DefinitVariable{ctr}%
\ifnum\thectr<16
\repeat

%==================================================================================
% Automation trial 1 :
%\iftrue
\iffalse
\newcommand\DeuxiemeAffecteVariable[1]{%%
    \setcounter{ctr}{1}%
    \expandafter\renewcommand\csname variable\Roman{ctr}\endcsname{\#1 (to point to the first argument within the function calling self function (ie \textbackslash variable1))}%
}

\newcommand\definecommand[1]{%%
  \expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{%
    \setcounter{ctr}{1}%
    \expandafter\DeuxiemeAffecteVariable{\arabic{ctr}}%
    }%%
}%


\definecommand{DefinitionVariablesN}%
\DefinitionVariablesN{Laetitia}%
La variable 1 est : \variableI  \\  FIN\\
\fi
%==================================================================================
% Automation trial 2 with xparse :
\iftrue
%\iffalse
\newcounter{cpteurLocal}
\NewDocumentCommand{\AffecteVariable}{m}
    {%
    \setcounter{cpteurLocal}{#1}%
    \expandafter\RenewDocumentCommand\csname variable\Roman{cpteurLocal}\endcsname {m}%
    {\#1 (to point to the first argument within the function calling self function (ie \textbackslash variable1))}%
    %{m}%
    %{##1}%
    %{########1}%
    %{contenu vraiable}%
    }%

% Macro factory (A)
\newcommand{\DefinitFonctionDeDefinition}[1]{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname DefinitionVariablesN\endcsname{%
            \expandafter\AffecteVariable{#1}%
            %\expandafter\expandafter\AffecteVariable{#1}%
            %\AffecteVariable{#1}%
        }%
    }

\setcounter{ctr}{1}%
\DefinitFonctionDeDefinition{\arabic{ctr}}%
\DefinitionVariablesN{Laetitia}

La variable 1 est : \variableI  \\  FIN\\
\fi

%==================================================================================

% Goal to reach, but this is 'handmade' (not scalable) :

\iffalse
%\iftrue
\newcommand{\DefinitionVariablesI}[9]{
    \renewcommand{\variableI}{#1}
    \renewcommand{\variableII}{#2}
    \renewcommand{\variableIII}{#3}
    \renewcommand{\variableIV}{#4}
    \renewcommand{\variableV}{#5}
    \renewcommand{\variableVI}{#6}
    \renewcommand{\variableVII}{#7}
    \renewcommand{\variableVIII}{#8}
    \renewcommand{\variableIX}{#9}
    }
\newcommand{\DefinitionVariablesII}[7]{
    \renewcommand{\variableX}{#1}
    \renewcommand{\variableXI}{#2}
    \renewcommand{\variableXII}{#3}
    \renewcommand{\variableXIII}{#4}
    \renewcommand{\variableXIV}{#5}
    \renewcommand{\variableXV}{#6}
    \renewcommand{\variableXVI}{#7}
    }

\DefinitionVariablesI{Laetitia}{Patrick}{Marie}{Michel}{Dieter}{Sammy}{Barbara}{Donna}{Ivan}
\DefinitionVariablesII{Pierre}{Rene}{Frederic}{Ousmam}{Paul}{Virginie}{Gerard}

La variable 1 est : \variableI\\
La variable 2 est : \variableII\\
La variable 3 est : \variableIII\\
La variable 4 est : \variableIV\\
La variable 5 est : \variableV\\
La variable 10 est : \variableX\\
La variable 11 est : \variableXI\\
La variable 12 est : \variableXII\\
La variable 13 est : \variableXIII\\
La variable 14 est : \variableXIV\\
FIN
\fi
\end{document}
```

======================================================================
Definitely making progress thx to @egreg answer.

Follow-up on [Macro factory and argument passed at calling (part 2)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367363/macro-factory-and-argument-passed-at-calling-part-2)

Comment: Thx for editing, it is indeed my first question here. I only have been a reader up to now.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Just for info: when you want to ping another user who commented your post, you have to put @ followed by the nickname, for example @clemens. Otherwise, he/she won't be notified.

Comment: @Aline Please, don't modify questions so as to invalidate existing answers. Ask a followup question instead.

Answer (score 6):

You can use some more advanced `expl3` tools:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\DefinitionVariables}{m}
 {
  \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
    \tl_clear_new:c { variable \int_to_Roman:n { \l_tmpa_int } } 
    \tl_set:cn { variable \int_to_Roman:n { \l_tmpa_int } } { ##1 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\DefinitionVariables{
  Laetitia,Patrick,Marie,Michel,Dieter,Sammy,Barbara,Donna,Ivan,
  Pierre,Rene,Frederic,Ousmam,Paul,Virginie,Gerard
}

\noindent
La variable 1 est : \variableI\\
La variable 2 est : \variableII\\
La variable 3 est : \variableIII\\
La variable 4 est : \variableIV\\
La variable 5 est : \variableV\\
La variable 10 est : \variableX\\
La variable 11 est : \variableXI\\
La variable 12 est : \variableXII\\
La variable 13 est : \variableXIII\\
La variable 14 est : \variableXIV\\
FIN

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a “classical” version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DefinitionVariables}[1]{%
  \count@=\z@
  \@for\next:={#1}\do{%
    \advance\count@\@ne
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname variable\@Roman\count@\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\next}% !!
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\DefinitionVariables{%
  Laetitia,Patrick,Marie,Michel,Dieter,Sammy,Barbara,Donna,Ivan,%
  Pierre,Rene,Frederic,Ousmam,Paul,Virginie,Gerard%
}

\noindent
La variable 1 est : \variableI\\
La variable 2 est : \variableII\\
La variable 3 est : \variableIII\\
La variable 4 est : \variableIV\\
La variable 5 est : \variableV\\
La variable 10 est : \variableX\\
La variable 11 est : \variableXI\\
La variable 12 est : \variableXII\\
La variable 13 est : \variableXIII\\
La variable 14 est : \variableXIV\\
FIN

\end{document}
```

To be on the safe side, it would be better using

```
\uppercase\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\df@temp\expandafter{%
    \romannumeral\count@
  }%
}%
\expandafter\newcommand\csname variable\df@temp\expandafter\endcsname
  \expandafter{\next}%
```

instead of the line marked as `!!`, because some `babel` modules redefine `\@Roman` in non expandable ways.

Note, however, that line ends need to be protected in the argument to `\DefineVariables`. This is not required in the `expl3` version, because `\clist_map_inline:nn` ignores spaces around the comma delimiters.

Comment: Thanks @egreg, I will study the package expl3. I was kind of avoiding it as it seems to be kind of non-latex/experimental.
The issue with your answer is that I cannot change the calling of the macro. In the MWE, it's first names, but it could be "name, family name, birth date", so with some comas.

Comment: @Aline I'll add a “classical” version.

Answer (score 4):

You can use some advanced TeX primitive tools:

```
\newcount\varnum
\def\DefinitionVariables#1{\varnum=0 \defvarA#1,\end,}
\def\defvarA#1#2,{%
   \ifx\end#1\else
      \advance\varnum by1
      \uppercase\expandafter
         {\expandafter\def\expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\romannumeral\varnum}}%
      \expandafter\def\csname variable\tmp\endcsname{#1#2}%
      \expandafter\defvarA\fi
}

\DefinitionVariables{
  Laetitia,Patrick,Marie,Michel,Dieter,Sammy,Barbara,Donna,Ivan,
  Pierre,Rene,Frederic,Ousmam,Paul,Virginie,Gerard
}

La variable 1 est : \variableI\\
La variable 2 est : \variableII\\
La variable 3 est : \variableIII\\
La variable 4 est : \variableIV\\
La variable 5 est : \variableV\\
La variable 10 est : \variableX\\
La variable 11 est : \variableXI\\
La variable 12 est : \variableXII\\
La variable 13 est : \variableXIII\\
La variable 14 est : \variableXIV\\
```