# Macro factory and argument passed at calling (part 2)

Tags: macros, expl3

I am making a factory macro (A) that produces another macro (B). Macro B consists in affecting what it gets as parameters to variables when called.
I am currently able to do all this without A, but this is not scalable, because it requires a lot of rewritting.

See [Macro factory and argument passed at calling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367335/macro-factory-and-argument-passed-at-calling)  for the whole context.

Following the answers on question the previous question ([Macro factory and argument passed at calling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367335/macro-factory-and-argument-passed-at-calling) ) , I could make a new MWE with some points still opened :

- point 1 : I put comas in the `\clist_map_inline` to artificially delimit each argument
- point 2 : I put the list of the argument in the definition (the 3 m) : `\NewDocumentCommand{\DefinitionVariables}{ m m m }%`
- point 3 : I put all the arguments in the `\clist_map_inline` function : `\clist_map_inline:nn { #1, #2, #3}%`

So the questions following these changes are :

- point 1 : How can I, not have to put a comas ? I guess it has to do with the `\clist_map_inline` function,  with coma being a built-in delimiter. It raises an issue when there is a coma inside an argument as the function will cut it as it considers it's a delimiter.
  I was thinking of having kind of a `\foreach argument in {all the arguments}`. Does such a thing exist ?
- point 2 : How can I make this m dynamic ? By dynamic, I mean : sometimes, the function can take 3 arguments, but sometimes it can be 7 or 9 (between 1 and 9). Something like `numberOfArgument * m`
- point 3 : It's related to the previous point, how can I also make this dynamic and not hard-coded ? (the `\foreach argument in {all the arguments}` would solve it).

  ```
  \documentclass[twoside]{article}
  % package pour utiliser une macro nested ac ses propres args
  \usepackage{xparse}
  \errorcontextlines32
  \begin{document}
  %==================================================================================
  %     Prerequisite : lines of code to define variableI to variableXVI
  %==================================================================================

  \iffalse
  \fi
  \newcommand{\DefinitVariable}[1]{%
      \expandafter\newcommand\csname variable\Roman{#1}\endcsname{}%
      }%
  %    Loop for defining all the variable
  \newcounter{ctr}
  \loop
      \stepcounter{ctr}
      \expandafter\DefinitVariable{ctr}%
  \ifnum\thectr<16
  \repeat
  %==================================================================================
  % Automation trial 5  : utilise la syntaxe expl3
  \iftrue
  %\iffalse

  \ExplSyntaxOn
  \NewDocumentCommand{\DefinitionVariables}{ m m m }%     <=== point 2 : there is as much 'm' as there is arguments
   {
    \int_zero:N \l_tmpa_int
    %\clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1, #2, #3}%         <=== point 3 : allows not to put comas in the arguments, but rise the pb if there is comas inside the argument // 
     {
      \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int
      \tl_clear_new:c { variable \int_to_Roman:n { \l_tmpa_int } } 
      \tl_set:cn { variable \int_to_Roman:n { \l_tmpa_int } } { ##1 }
     }
   }
  \ExplSyntaxOff

  \DefinitionVariables{Laetitia, 8 }{Pierre, 10}{Cedric}%        <=== point 1 : coma inside the argument will be considered as a delimiter, so the mapping of variable will be wrong
  La variable 2 est : \variableII  \\  FIN\\
  La variable 1 est : \variableI  \\  FIN\\
  La variable 3 est : \variableIII  \\  FIN\\
  La variable 1 est : \variableI  \\  FIN\\
  \fi
  ```

Any help is very appreciate !

Comment: I'm not sure what the expansion of `\variableI` should be. Should it be “Laetitia, 8”?

Comment: Yes, it should be the parameter passed.
@egreg :
I don't get why you are reformulating the call of \DefinitionVariables. The syntax is \DefinitionVariables{arg1}..{argX}..{argN} with X = 1 to X = N (N is 9 at max).
Is this a latex rule ?

Comment: With passing a comma separated list (or anyhow delimited) you can override the limit of nine arguments.

Comment: Ah ok. Nice, but I still need to pass the arguments with the syntax of each argument being a real argument.

I tried to put }{ as a delimiter, but an error is occuring.

Comment: Why should it be necessary to use the `{...}{...}` syntax? This limits you to nine arguments.

Comment: Because the calling is this way since the arguments are used in other functions. Also because it would be difficult to choose a delimiter as we don't know in advance what characters will be in the arguments.

Comment: I added a different routine. But my idea is that you're asking an [XY-question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A development version of the previous code; the new `\DefinitionVariables` accepts two optional arguments, the fixed name and the delimiter; the latter is (almost) completely arbitrary, just choose a character (or combination thereof) that doesn't appear in the values you want to give the variables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\DefinitionVariables}{O{variable}mO{,}}
 {
  \aline_df:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\int_new:N \l_aline_df_int
\seq_new:N \l_aline_df_values_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \aline_df:nnn
 {
  \int_zero:N \l_aline_df_int
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_aline_df_values_seq { #3 } { #2 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_aline_df_values_seq
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_aline_df_int
    \tl_clear_new:c { #1 \int_to_Roman:n { \l_aline_df_int } } 
    \tl_set:cn { #1 \int_to_Roman:n { \l_aline_df_int } } { ##1 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\DefinitionVariables{
  Laetitia, 8; Patrick, 10; Cedric
}[;]

\noindent
La variable 1 est : \variableI\\
La variable 2 est : \variableII\\
La variable 3 est : \variableIII\\
FIN

\bigskip

\DefinitionVariables[var]{A,B,C}

\noindent
La var 1 est : \varI\\
La var 2 est : \varII\\
La var 3 est : \varIII\\
FIN

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different routine based on a recursion for allowing the arguments to be delimited by braces. So long as an open brace follows, a new variable is defined.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\DefinitionVariables}{O{variable}}
 {% pass control to an inner function
  % #1 is the "name part", default "variable"
  \aline_df:n { #1 }
 }

% define an integer variable
\int_new:N \l_aline_df_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \aline_df:n
 {
  % the integer variable assigns the trailing roman number
  \int_zero:N \l_aline_df_int
  % start the recursion
  \__aline_df_peek:n { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__aline_df_peek:n
 {
  % check whether the next token is { (ignoring spaces)
  \peek_catcode_ignore_spaces:NT \c_group_begin_token
   {
    % if it is, increment the counter and call
    % \__aline_df_next:nn { #1 } { #2 }, where
    % { #2 } is the next braced group
    \int_incr:N \l_aline_df_int
    \__aline_df_next:nn { #1 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__aline_df_next:nn
 {
  % if the variable is already defined, clear it
  % otherwise create it
  \tl_clear_new:c { #1 \int_to_Roman:n { \l_aline_df_int } }
  % set the variable
  \tl_set:cn { #1 \int_to_Roman:n { \l_aline_df_int } } { #2 }
  % restart the recursion
  \__aline_df_peek:n { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\DefinitionVariables{Laetitia, 8}{Patrick, 10}{Cedric}

\noindent
La variable 1 est : \variableI\\
La variable 2 est : \variableII\\
La variable 3 est : \variableIII\\
FIN

\bigskip

\DefinitionVariables[var]{A}{B}{C}{D}{E}{F}{G}{H}{I}{J}{K}

\noindent
La var 1 est : \varI\\
La var 2 est : \varII\\
La var 3 est : \varIII\\
La var 11 est : \varXI\\
FIN

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for the answer, this is definitely addressing point 2 and 3.

Comment: Fantastic !!! This is exactly what I needed !
I will put myself into expl3 and study it a bit more.
Thx a lot @egreg for this answer and all the back and forth.

Comment: @Aline I added some comments to the code