# Define a variable dynamically, but it is not persistent

Tags: expl3

I have a macro that generates variables dynamically when called (see [Macro factory and argument passed at calling (part 2)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367363/macro-factory-and-argument-passed-at-calling-part-2) for the full history of the build).

I wanted to add a constant which represents the length of the list of arguments. The idea being that when called with {Pierre}{Jacques} the macro defines variableI (set to Pierre), variableII (set to Jacques) but also variableConstanteLongueur (set to 2).

It's working almost as intended : when I define more than one serie of variable, the ConstanteLongueur takes the value of the length of the last serie that was defined instead of taking the value of the lenght of his serie.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
% package pour utiliser une macro nested ac ses propres args
\usepackage{xparse}
% package pour avoir foreach
\usepackage{tikz}
\errorcontextlines32
\begin{document}

%==================================================================================
%    Macro that define the variables and the variable ConstanteLongueur which is the lenght of the list
%==================================================================================
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\DefinitionVariables}{O{variable}}
 {% pass control to an inner function
  % #1 is the "name part", default "variable"
  \aline_df:n { #1 }
 }

% define an integer variable
\int_new:N \l_aline_df_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \aline_df:n
 {
  % the integer variable assigns the trailing roman number
  \int_zero:N \l_aline_df_int
  % start the recursion
  \__aline_df_peek:n { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__aline_df_peek:n
 {
  % check whether the next token is { (ignoring spaces)
  \peek_catcode_ignore_spaces:NT \c_group_begin_token
   {
    % if it is, increment the counter and call
    % \__aline_df_next:nn { #1 } { #2 }, where
    % { #2 } is the next braced group
    \int_incr:N \l_aline_df_int
    \__aline_df_next:nn { #1 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__aline_df_next:nn
 {
  % if the variable is already defined, clear it
  % otherwise create it
  \tl_clear_new:c { #1 \int_to_Roman:n { \l_aline_df_int } }
  \tl_clear_new:c { #1 ConstanteLongueur }
  % set the variable
  \tl_set:cn { #1 \int_to_Roman:n { \l_aline_df_int }}  { #2 }
  \tl_set:cn { #1 ConstanteLongueur } { \int_eval:n  { \l_aline_df_int } }

  % restart the recursion
  \__aline_df_peek:n { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
%==================================================================================
%     Code to be executed
%==================================================================================
\DefinitionVariables[variableNames]{Armelle}{Audrey}{Philippe}{Maxime}{Thierry}{Myriam}
\DefinitionVariables[variableColors]{yellow}{blue}{green}{red}


Longueur de variableColors, should print the number 4 :
\variableColorsConstanteLongueur

\variableColorsI

Longueur de variableNames, should print the number 6 :
\variableNamesConstanteLongueur

\variableNamesI


==============================\\After re-defining the variable Names\\==============================

\DefinitionVariables[variableNames]{Armelle}{Audrey}{Philippe}{Maxime}{Thierry}{Myriam}

Longueur de variableNames, should print the number 6 :
\variableNamesConstanteLongueur

\end{document}
```

As you can see, the serie that begins with "Armelle" is 6 in length and the one beginning with "yellow" is 4.

But when called `\variableNamesConstanteLongueur` gives 4 instead of 6 ; it's puzzling since the definition of the variables are ok (\variableNamesI is correctly "Armelle").

Do you have any idea what did I missed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is

```
\tl_set:cn { #1 ConstanteLongueur } { \int_eval:n  { \l_aline_df_int } }
```

This will create the token list you want with content *exactly* `\int_eval:n  { \l_aline_df_int }`. What you want is the *result* of that at the point of definition: currently it is evaluated at point of use. Thus

```
\tl_set:cx { #1 ConstanteLongueur } { \int_eval:n  { \l_aline_df_int } }
```

*i.e.* carrying out exhaustive expansion.

Comment: Great, thx a lot for the accurate and quick answer !

Answer (score 3):

You need to fully expand the value when storing it.

I'd suggest a different approach, instead of peeking for a brace: using clists is easier.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\DefinitionVariables}{O{variable}m}
 {% pass control to an inner function
  % #1 is the "name part", default "variable"
  \aline_df:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\int_new:N \l_aline_df_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \aline_df:nn
 {
  \int_zero:N \l_aline_df_int
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_aline_df_int
    \tl_clear_new:c { #1 \int_to_Roman:n { \l_aline_df_int } }
    \tl_set:cn { #1 \int_to_Roman:n { \l_aline_df_int }}  { ##1 }
   }
  \tl_clear_new:c { #1 ConstanteLongueur }
  \tl_set:cx { #1 ConstanteLongueur } { \int_eval:n { \l_aline_df_int } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\DefinitionVariables[variableNames]{
  Armelle,
  Audrey,
  Philippe,
  Maxime,
  Thierry,
  Myriam
}
\DefinitionVariables[variableColors]{
  yellow,
  blue,
  green,
  red
}


Longueur de variableColors, should print the number 4:
\variableColorsConstanteLongueur

\variableColorsI

Longueur de variableNames, should print the number 6:
\variableNamesConstanteLongueur

\variableNamesI

\DefinitionVariables[variableNames]{
  Armelle,
  Audrey,
  Philippe,
  Maxime,
  Thierry,
  Myriam
}

Longueur de variableNames, should print the number 6:
\variableNamesConstanteLongueur

\variableNamesIII

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx for the proposal, unfortunately the variable could contain coma.